# Marquee In React Js with start &stop effect

Tags: html, reactjs

How to create marquee in react with On Mouse Over and On Mouse Out( Stop & Start) effect.
i have tried this code.

```
<Marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" onMouseOver={this.stop} onMouseOut={this.start}>Hello</marquee>
```

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Comment: Where is the `<Marquee/>` element coming from?  Is that an existing component or is it from a library?  Which library?

Answer (score 0):

In React JS you can use This code.

```
<marquee behavior='scroll' direction="left" onMouseOver={(e)=>{e.target.stop()}} onMouseOut={(e)=>{e.target.start()}} style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '3em' }} >Test</marquee>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">Hello</marquee>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<marquee>` element has been [dead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) for a while now.

Comment: Not only that but it has never been part of any HTML specification except HTML5 and only for the sole purpose of marking it as obsolete. In addition, that doctype is obsolete.

Comment: doctype is of html 4, then it will work in all browsers?

Comment: All browsers will support Marquee tag?

Comment: I want to create this in React js .

Comment: I don't know reactjs but try: onMouseOut={this.start()}